how do I fix \operatorname adding a space on the left
Why does \operatorname{} add a space on the left, e.g. something like:
$$|\operatorname{I}|$$

I'm not sure how to fix this.

I'm not quite seeing what you're seeing.  Could you turn this into a MWE?  Meanwhile, see Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?.

Use \lvert \operatorname{} \rvert.

This is a known issue, due to the following facts:

| is defined as an ordinary symbol;
between an ordinary symbol and an operator, TeX adds a thin space.

You want this in expressions such as 2\sin x, but |\sin x| turns out wrong.
Load amsmath and use
\lvert <math formula> \rvert

any time you want absolute values independent of what the <math formula> contains, operators or whatever.
